# Adding outliers to plotly boxplot properly

Tags: python, plotly

I am building a serie of boxplots with pre calculated data using plotly graphic_objects. My problem comes when I need to send the outliers list for each plot. I did not find a proper way of sendding them.

My code looks like this:

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Box(x = df.mes, y = df.json_agg, mean = df.media, q1 = df.p25, median = df.mediana, q3 = df.p75, lowerfence = df.li, upperfence = df.ls))

fig.update_xaxes(
                   dtick="M1",
                   tickformat="%m-%Y",
                   ticklabelmode="period")

fig.show()
```

And my final plot:

[image]

What I need is the outliers propertly shown on top or bottop of each boxplot, not side by side.

Thanks, you all help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

- have simulated data to make your code sample work
- whenever I try passing **q3** plot fails to build
- the parameter you need to show outliers is **boxpoints** https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/#styling-outliers

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

S = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "mes": np.random.choice(pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", freq="M", periods=10), S),
        "json_agg": np.random.uniform(-0.4, 0.5, S) * np.random.uniform(0.1, 1, S),
    }
)

df = (
    df.groupby("mes", as_index=False)
    .apply(
        lambda d: d.assign(
            media=d["json_agg"].mean(),
            p25=np.percentile(d["json_agg"], 25),
            p75=np.percentile(d["json_agg"], 75),
            mediana=np.percentile(d["json_agg"], 50),
            li=np.percentile(d["json_agg"], 20),
            ls=np.percentile(d["json_agg"], 80),
        )
    )
    .sort_values("mes")
)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(
        x=df.mes,
        y=df.json_agg,
        mean=df.media,
        q1=df.p25,
#         q3=df.p75,
        median=df.mediana,
        lowerfence=df.li,
        upperfence=df.ls,
        boxpoints="outliers",
    )
)

# fig.update_xaxes(dtick="M1", tickformat="%m-%Y", ticklabelmode="period")
```

[image]